# How can I make multiple subplots based on a common date column and each other column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, for-loop, plot, plotly, subplot

I have this dataframe and I want to create a subplot for each exercise, depicting the sum of sets for each date in a trend line format.

I have tried grouping the dataframe by date and summing the grouped values

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 3))
grouped_data = data.groupby('Date').sum().sort_values(by = 'Date', ascending = True)
grouped_data
```

I want to depict that result in a trend line format for each exercise.

Thank you.

[image: Screenshot]
[image]

Edit 1) :

I have tried dtBane's solution and I get the following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\1564~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17636/3887961625.py in <module>
      3 for col in data.columns:
      4     y = data[col]
----> 5     z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
      6     p = np.poly1d(z)
      7     plt.plot(x,p(x),"--")

<__array_function__ internals> in polyfit(*args, **kwargs)

C:\Conda\envs\frame\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py in polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond, full, w, cov)
    658     scale = NX.sqrt((lhs*lhs).sum(axis=0))
    659     lhs /= scale
--> 660     c, resids, rank, s = lstsq(lhs, rhs, rcond)
    661     c = (c.T/scale).T  # broadcast scale coefficients
    662 

<__array_function__ internals> in lstsq(*args, **kwargs)

C:\Conda\envs\frame\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in lstsq(a, b, rcond)
   2304         # lapack can't handle n_rhs = 0 - so allocate the array one larger in that axis
   2305         b = zeros(b.shape[:-2] + (m, n_rhs + 1), dtype=b.dtype)
-> 2306     x, resids, rank, s = gufunc(a, b, rcond, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
   2307     if m == 0:
   2308         x[...] = 0

C:\Conda\envs\frame\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in _raise_linalgerror_lstsq(err, flag)
     98 
     99 def _raise_linalgerror_lstsq(err, flag):
--> 100     raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares")
    101 
    102 def get_linalg_error_extobj(callback):

LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares
```

Edit 2)

When I try Rpanai's solution I get this output, which does not look very elegant. Also, it would be great if the hours(00:00) in the x axis could be hidden.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use both `pandas` or `plotly`. I'm using the same data as @dtBane.

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'Pushups': [1,4,3,5,9],
        'Squats': [1,1,2,2,3],
        'Biceps Curls':[7,2,9,3,2], 
        'Date':['2020-11-12',
                '2020-11-12',
                '2020-11-13',
                '2020-11-13',
                '2020-11-14']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# Group by automatically sort the values
grp = df.groupby('Date').sum()
```

## Plotly

```py
import plotly.express as px
px.line(grp)
```

[image]

## Pandas

```py
grp.plot();
```

[image]

**EDIT**

## Subplots

In order to have subplots you can first convert your data from wide format to long and then use `plotly.express` again.

### Wide to long

```py
df1 = pd.melt(grp, var_name="Exercise", ignore_index=False)
print(df1)
```

```sh
                Exercise  value
Date                           
2020-11-12       Pushups      5
2020-11-13       Pushups      8
2020-11-14       Pushups      9
2020-11-12        Squats      2
2020-11-13        Squats      4
2020-11-14        Squats      3
2020-11-12  Biceps Curls      9
2020-11-13  Biceps Curls     12
2020-11-14  Biceps Curls      2
```

### Plotly using facet

```py
px.line(df1,
        y='value',
        facet_col='Exercise',
        facet_col_spacing=0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, I am afraid that this is not the solution I was looking for as I need to create a trend line for each exercise in a separate chart/subplot , not every exercise in one chart/plot.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer. Do you mind to check if this is what are you looking for?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. Please see the new edit of my initial post.

Comment: Here you should have a look at [how-to-ask]? My bad as I misunderstand your question at the beginning (not subplot) but you can't keep asking further modification to your question in this way. You better ask a different question regarding new problems you are facing.

Comment: Yes, will do , thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (example on random data):

```
data = {'Pushups':[1,4,3,5,9],'Squats':[1,1,2,2,3],'Biceps Curls':[7,2,9,3,2], 'Date':['12-11-2020','12-11-2020','13-11-2020','13-11-2020','14-11-2020']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df = df.groupby('Date').sum()

x = np.arange(len(df.index))
for col in df.columns:
    y = df[col]
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    p = np.poly1d(z)
    plt.plot(x,p(x),"--")

plt.show()
```

If you want only trendlines, just remove `plt.scatter` lines.